# Combine 2 tables and sort them by date field and output the result as a list

Tags: php, mysql

How do I combine 2 tables sort them by date and output them into a list?
Here's what I currently have.

The date in the list should be this format 2015-06-27 23:00

```
SELECT date, name, quantity, FROM downloads ORDER BY(`Date`) DESC
SELECT date, name, quantity, price, FROM sales ORDER BY(`Date`) DESC


$result_sales = $mysqli->query($sql_sales);

while($row = $result_sales->fetch_assoc()){
       $sale = rown["quantity"];
       $name = row["name"]; 
       $date_str = strtotime($row["date"]);
       $year = date('Y', $date_str);
       $month = date('n', $date_str) - 1;
       $day = date('j', $date_str);
       $hour = date('H', $date_str);
       $minute = date('i', $date_str);
       $ans_sales = " " . sprintf('%s, %s, %s, %s, %s',$year,$month,$day,$hour,minute) . " - ".  $name ." - " .  $sale . " - Sale Added";
       echo $ans_sales . ",\r\n";
}
```

Comment: You want those 2 result sets combined?

Comment: Yes, so that I can output them both into a list

Comment: Does the `downloads` table also have a `price` column?

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen  no it does not have the price column

Comment: Are downloads a certain type of sales?  In other words, are the downloads records also contained within the sales table?

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen no downloads are different type from sales

Comment: Then @tmack 's answer might be what you are looking for.  When you perform a `UNION` in MySQL both tables have to have the same number of columns.  This will necessitate putting a dummy value for price in the `downloads` table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT date, name, quantity, 0 as price FROM downloads
union all
SELECT date, name, quantity, price FROM sales
ORDER BY(`Date`) DESC
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution I choose this solution to work with, seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `,` near `FROM` .

```
SELECT date, name, quantity, price, FROM sales ORDER BY(`Date`) DESC
                                  ^^
```

And for combining two table use UNION ALL

```
(SELECT date, name, quantity FROM downloads ORDER BY `Date` DESC)

UNION ALL

(SELECT date, name, quantity, price FROM sales ORDER BY `Date` DESC)


ORDER BY `Date` DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a mysql VIEW 'view_all' with the query

```
SELECT 
        date, 
        name, 
        quantity,
        null as price
    FROM downloads 

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        date, 
        name, 
        quantity, 
        price
    FROM sales
```

then execute

SELECT * FROM 'view_all' ORDER BY(`date`) DESC;